# Should I assign my DTO properties to public variables or call the dto instance directly on my aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dto

My UI layer calls my business layer which populates a DTO.  I need to display properties from the DTO on my ASPX page.  Should I create public variables on the code behind page for each of the DTO properties and reference like `<%=PublicPropertyName%>` OR is it ok to set the DTO instance to public and reference the properties directly like `<%=dtoInstance.propertyName%>`

Additionally, would it be better if I just created Literal and Label controls for every item on the ASPX page and just populate them from the code behind only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the public variables within the code behind would be somewhat similar to Fowler's Presentation Model pattern. This would allow your DTOs to evolve over time and only require modification to the code that transforms the DTOs and assigns their values to the code behind object. That would definitely be a valid approach.

Comment: I should have been more clear (will edit).  In the 2nd case where I reference the dto directly, I have set it as a public variable in the code behind.

Comment: It really is a matter of the complexity and likelyhood of change of the project. If you expose the DTO as a member of your code behind, you would be creating a strong dependency between your view and the DTO (which when shared among several views has a very high likelyhood of changing). This means anytime you change the DTO you will probably have to go back and refactor more of your views to accept the new DTO. I would go with the first case.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your question, boils down to whether you want to provide direct access to your variables without a property.  I'm pretty certain that exposing variables publicly violates encapsulation and lets clients see too much of your class.

As for literals etc....
Might be worth taking a look at the FormView control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf1dk77%28VS.85%29.aspx

To make handling of this a cinch (spelling?!)